# How to use fixture files in Magento2 Integration test?

Tags: magento2, integration-test

I am beginner in integration testing and I need a brief highlight on concept of using fixture files in Magento 2 Integration Testing .
    I tried with following simple code to test what impact in integration test in db and what it returns :

**Vendor\Module\Tests\Integration_files\Config.php**

```
<?php
$model = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()
    ->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface::class);
$model->save('web/unsecure/base_url',  'http://mymagento.com/');
$model->save('web/secure/base_url',  'https://mymagento.com/');
```

file location : **Vendor\Module\Tests\Integration\Block\Form\LoginTest**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Tests\Integration\Block\Form;

use Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap;

class LoginTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public static function loadFixture()
    {
        include __DIR__ . '/../../_files/Config.php';
    }

    /**
     * @magentoDbIsolation enabled
     * @magentoAppIsolation enabled
     * @magentoDataFixture loadFixture
     */
    public function testGetFormActionUrl()
    {
        $urlBuilder = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create('\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        $this->assertSame('http://mymagento.com/frontname/controller/action/', $urlBuider->getUrl('frontname/controller/action/'));
    }
}
```

**After executing test** :

```
1. builder return URL : http://localhost/index.php/frontname/controller/action/ (So it give false assertion because expected is 'http://mymagento.com/frontname/controller/action/' )
```

Comment: Vendor\Module\Tests\Integration_files\Config.php should be Vendor\Module\Tests\Integration\_files\Config.php